# Getting params as a list of key/value tuple

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm implementing a RESTful url, so I could filter my query with for example `/api/v1.0/events?filter[title]="foo"&filter[content]="bar"`

Is there an existing way to get all the `filter` as `[("title", "foo"), ("content", "bar")]`?

Comment: What would you like to do with such a type? Apparently, I see no reason for putting a list inside a `Maybe` because `Just v` can be encoded as a singleton list (`[v]`) and `Nothing` can be encoded as an empty list (`[]`). Could you clarify your goals?

Comment: I've updated the question to remove the Maybe. Now it's just a list of tuples. Still not sure how to get it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll create a Parser with attoparsec to take a string like `"filter[title]"`, and return `"title"` from that:

```
import Data.Attoparsec.Text

filterParser :: Parser Text
filterParser = do
    _ <- string "filter["
    filterKey <- takeTill (== ']')
    _ <- string "]"
    return filterKey
```

Get the query string parameters, a list of `(Text, Text)`, and parse them into `(filterKey, filterValue)` pairs:

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do

    params <- reqGetParams <$> getRequest -- (1)

    let filters = catMaybes $ map (\(queryParam, filterValue) -> case maybeResult $ parse filterParser queryParam of     -- (2) (4)
                    Nothing -> Nothing          -- (3)
                    Just filterKey -> Just (filterKey, filterValue)     -- (3)
                  ) params
    liftIO $ print $ "Params are " ++ show filters
```

1. Get the query string parameters using `reqGetParams`
2. `parse` from attoparsec applies a `Parser` (`filterParser`) to the key part of the query string. We immediately make that into a `Maybe` using `maybeResult` from attoparsec. If the parse succeeds, we get a `Just "title"`, or if it fails (the query param didn't look like `"filter=[foo]"`) we get `Nothing`.
3. If the param was a filter, return `Just (filterKey, filterValue)`, otherwise `Nothing`.
4. Use `catMaybes` to remove all `Nothing`s from the list, giving us just the `[(filterKey, filterValue)]` pairs.

Caveats:

1. This code doesn't handle escaping. I doubt you need to support something like `"filter[foo\]bar]"` though.
2. This code doesn't remove the quotes around the query param values. I think you should just not send those if possible, since you aren't using them.
3. I'm not very good at writing parsing code. You could use a regexp instead if you wanted to.

Comment: wow, thanks for the detailed answer! Didn't imagine saying this, but this is where I miss PHP's $_GET -- It does all the parsing "for free" ;)

Comment: (btw, closest URL parser that I found is https://github.com/Soostone/uri-bytestring/blob/master/src/URI/ByteString/Internal.hs#L142)